# Cannot find module 'xmlbuilder' when building ionic app

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

When i executing

```
ionic start myApp tabs
```

i am getting below error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'xmlbuilder'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:12:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/xml2js/lib/xml2js.js:436:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
```

`node -v` gives `v4.4.1`
`npm -v` gives `2.14.20`

i have done `npm install xmlbuilder`

Answer (score 1):

Please install xmlbuilder module to global environment:

```
npm install -g xmlbuilder
```